# Compare stock chart series in Python Highcharts

Tags: python, charts

I am using pandas-highcharts which is a wrapper for Highcharts in Python.  When using the type=stock, I'd like to be able to compare two series in the chart by percentage change dynamically based on the window of data showing in the chart at the time.  I'm aware that this can be done with the plotOptions.series.compare=percent, but I can't figure out how to write it into the pandas-highcharts code.  Here's what I have so far, everything works except that option.

```
display_charts(dualmom_1y_ret[['US Equity', 'Intl Equity']], chart_type='stock', compare='percent')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The functionality is being added. Check the pull request [here](https://github.com/gtnx/pandas-highcharts/pull/46)